# How to fix "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" in Symfony4.2

Tags: symfony-4.2

I am getting Error:

> Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded every time I add
>   `CountryType field` to any form in `Symfony 4.2`

In `Symfony 4.2 FormType`, I have `CountryType field` added to the form and when it is added, any controller using that form returns the error **"Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded"**

I've tried to increase the `max_execution_time` in `php.in` to `120`, but still getting the same error but for `120 seconds`.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('clientName')
            ->add('email', TextType::class, array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'data-role' => 'tagsinput'
                )
            ))
            ->add('phone')
            ->add('mobile')
            ->add('country', CountryType::class)
            ->add('city')
            ->add('addressLine1')
            ->add('addressLine2')
            ->add('active', CheckboxType::class, array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'sp-hidden'
                ),
                'label' => false,
                'label_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'sp-hidden'
                ),
                'required' => false
            ))
        ;
    }
```

Comment: Does your `country` field in your entity have a relationship to any other entity/field? I've run into this problem with bi-directional OneToOne relationships.

Comment: Nope. I was an issue with the Symfony version. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @AhmedAgha would you mind posting a full answer with the details on how it was fixed?